# Looking for anti-spam software

Tags: linux, email, spam

I am looking for a mail anti-spam software appliance that would merely and solely check for spam and make [RBL](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNS-based_Blackhole_List) checks. There is plethora of such appliances online, however, all of them require to act as MX gateways which I do not want.

In essence, I want to plug the spam appliance into my already existing e-mail chain:

```
MX gateway --> smtp1 --> smtp2 --> antispam appliance --> end user email server
```

All pieces of software available on the Internet want to tinker with my DNS or require reconfiguration of my already existing email chain. What I need is a simple box which will accept all e-mails, check them against spam, and send them to a designated server.

Any ideas if something is available out there alike? Preferably in omv/vsphere format.

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! Do you have any preference to the OS on which this should be running? Do you want an actual physical "box" that already ships with this or are you looking for a tool to be installed?

Comment: Hi, I'm with Linux (preferrably). It does not really matter whether it is a physical box or a virtual appliance. Would be also great if I could somehow test it.

Comment: Someone I talked to today mentioned spamassasin for this task, but as I did not use it myself (or can verify that it works in this setup), I won't post it as recommendation.

Comment: I gathered a couple of answers, DSPAM, appRiver and SpamTitan are what I am looking at now. I will update this when I choose something eventually.